# Database structur for a tutorial website

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need help with the database structure. 
I try to explain it.

- every user can create a tutorial
- every tutorial have steps (Step 1, Step 2, ...)

Now i created a database with the name **Tutorial-Database**, inside the DB is a table with the name **Tutorial**. The table **Tutorial**, have this attributes

- tutorial_id = the id of each tutorial
- tutorial_title = the title of each tutorial
- tutorial_iamge = you can add a image, at the beginning of each tutorial
- tutorial_description = you can explain the tutorial
- tutorial_steps = how many steps the tutorial have

Every tutorial are splitted up in a few steps.

**My Question:** I dont know how to save the steps, here i created a little model:

[ER Model](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=774ea8-1430063387.png)

Should i save all steps of all tutorial in one table? Or should i create 10 (10 steps) tables. One table for one step.

Comment: Easy. One table. Well, two tables. A table for tutorials, and a table for steps.

Comment: all in 1 table, with columns to link to `\`Tutorial\`.\`tutorial_id\`` and which step. `tutorial_steps` could be redundant/unnecessary as you could always count how many rows are in the steps table.

Comment: I create then a table with the name **Tutorial_steps** and i put every step inside the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following
`Tutorial` table -> Contain details like tutorial name , description etc.

`Tutorial_steps` table -> Contain Tutorial's primary key as foreign key in Tutorial_steps table. Like

`Tutorial_steps : id , tutorial_id , step_number, Your custom fields here`. Hope you got it.

Comment: Thanks alot! Because i created 10 tables... But i will delete Them all and create one for all steps, thanks!

Comment: @Skeptar welcome. And think if your 1 tutorial has 10 steps , one has 4,one has 6 then how would you manage code with 10 tables ?? Say if one tutorial contains 20 steps , will you manually create another 10 tables ? **:)**  , if it solves your issue , you can do Upvote and accept  answer , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting to accomplish is create a [One to Many relationship](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/).  You can accomplish this by creating 1 or 2 more tables (based on your preference) to create that association.

You could create table **Steps** which would have something like `id(int),name(text),...` and you could associate those steps with a Tutorial by an intermediary table called an [XREF (or Junction Table)](http://forums.sqlmag.com/forums/aft/65203).  That table could be called something like, **TutorialStepsXref** and might look something like this with fields `tutorial_id(int),step_id(int)`

Comment: Step id will not be proper because , for every tutorial , Step number say 2 will be different so , step_id wont be needed here. Instead you should use step_number column in  `TutorialStepsXref` table you have

Comment: Both ID columns are intended to be foreign keys

Comment: Ok say step_id comes from some table `steps` . Now the step table will have structure like id, step_name, step_description. Correct? But see , you can have the table (with 2 foreign keys) Only if there is Many to Many relationshoip. but its 1 to many relationship. Means 1 tutorial -> Many steps . Its not 1 step belong to Many tutorial, so its only 1 way , one to many relationship. So no need of table  containing 2 foreign keys. Getting ?

Comment: My recommendation, by definition, does not force anything to have ownership.. the exact opposite is true.  You could re-use any step with any number of tutorials.  

The TutorialStepsXref maps any step to any tutorial.  If you had Tutorial 1 and Tutorial 2.. you could, for the sake of demonstration, map the same 10 steps to both.  I don't know why you down voted, or why you're arguing this.